# Number of solutions to $x^3 - c^2x^2 + p^2 \equiv 0 \mod p^3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I would like to find the number of solutions ($\mod p^3$) to $x^3 - c^2x^2 + p^2 \equiv 0 \mod p^3$, where $p$ is prime and $c$ is an integer not divisible by $p$.  I think [Hensel's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma) will be useful, but I'm not entirely sure how to apply it.
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To apply Hensel's lemma, suppose $f(x) = x^3 - c^2x^2 + p^2 \equiv 0\ (p)$. It follows that $x^2(x - c^2) \equiv 0\ (p)$, so either $p \mid x$ or $p \mid x - c^2$. Assume $p \nmid x$, then $3x - 2c^2 \equiv 3x - 2x \equiv x \not\equiv 0\ (p)$. This will correspond to a solution modulo $p^3$ according to the lemma.

Comment: @J.H.  So in the case that $p \nmid x$, is the number of solutions $\mod p^3$ equal to the number of solutions of $f(x) \equiv 0 \mod p$?

Answer (score 4):

If $x$ satisfies $x^3 - c^2x^2 + p^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {p^3}$, $x$ also satisfies
$$x^3 - c^2x^2 + p^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {p^2}$$
So $x^2(x-c^2)\equiv 0 \pmod {p^2}$. So $x$ satisfies  $p\mid x$ or $p^2\mid(x-c^2)$ and $x$ satisfies only one formula. (Because $c$ is not disible by $p$.)

If $p\mid x$, then there exists $y\in\mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $x=py$. Substitute $x$ with $py$ then we get
$$(1-c^2y^2)p^2\equiv 0\pmod{p^3}$$
This formula is equivalent to
$$1-c^2y^2\equiv 0\pmod{p}$$
So the number of $y$ is 2, namely $y\equiv c^{-1} \pmod{p}$ and $y\equiv-c^{-1} \pmod{p}$. So $x\equiv \pm c^{-1} p + kp^2 \pmod{p^3}$ ($k$ is arbitary integer) is solution of this equation, therefore the number of this equation is $2p$.

If $p^2\mid(x-c^2)$, then there exists $z$ s.t. $x=c^2+zp^2$. Substitute $x$ with $c^2+zp^2$ and rearrange it then we get
$$c^4 zp^2 +p^2\equiv 0 \pmod{p^3}$$

This equation is equivalent to
$$c^4 z + 1\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$
and it has only one soultion $z\equiv 1 \pmod p$, so the number of solutions of this equation is $2p+1$.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by $\bigg(\frac{c}{p}\bigg)$?  You say the number of $x$ is equal to $1 + \bigg(\frac{c}{p}\bigg)$ but this is not an integer.

Comment: @Jack See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol)

Comment: The second line should read $x^2(x - c^2) \equiv 0\ (p^2)$?

Comment: @J.H. What does it mean ?

Comment: I think it should be $c^2$ instead of $c$.

Comment: @J.H. thanks to point out my mistakes.

Comment: Couple of mistakes. Firstly, when you substitute $x=py$, shouldn't you get $(1-c^2y^2)p^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p^3}$, and not $(1-c^4y^2)p^2$? Secondly, the number of solutions for $y \pmod{p}$ for the equation $(1-c^2y^2) \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ is 2, namely $\pm c^{-1}$. Thirdly, you want the number of solutions for $x \pmod{p^3}$, so since $x=py$, that corresponds to the number of solutions for $y \pmod{p^2}$. You need to multiply by $p$ to get a total of $2p$. Fourthly, your second case should read ``there exists $z$ s.t. $x=c^2+zp^2$" and not $x=c+zp^2$.

Comment: @Tetori your substitution of $x=c^2+zp^2$ is wrong as well. Please recheck all your algebraic manipulation again.

Comment: @IvanLoh I fixed my mistakes. It is no problem?

Comment: Please read my comments above. In particular refer to the 1st and 3rd point.

Comment: @IvanLoh I corrected these points that you have pointed out. It is okay?

Comment: It seems ok now. +1 for the effort.